# php allowing access to directory based on user type

Tags: php, security, authentication

I have the following table:

```
tbl_users
===============
uid
username
password
gid

tbl_groups
===============
gid
name
type
```

And i have the following directories

```
admin/
user/
sales/
```

How would i be able to restrict access to those folders based on user group, so only admin group can get to admin folder, and user group can get to user folder and so on?

Comment: You could create a script that checks the user's group (maybe in a session variable) and then check the directory that they are in. If the two don't match, redirect. Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could forbid access to subfolders and set rewrite rules in .htacces to transparently redirect to a PHP script. There you can serve the contents with your own permission system. On client side it looks as you would access the folders directly.